# Existing report is not getting Download in OpenOfiice

Tags: openerp-7, odoo, openerp-8, openoffice-writer, odoo-8

I am trying to modify already existing report in Open Office(ex. Point of sale receipt ) . But when I select it to download , it is showing an error like this

> > Could not be Download 
> >     ***URL seems to be an unsupported one .***

How can I fix this error .

Comment: IMHO this question is off-topic here. Just moving it to superuser.com wouldn't solve this, because it's unclear what you've tried exactly (which steps) to "modify" an "existing report". So, to prevent this question from getting immediately closed on superuser, you should add much more details.